# get empty array when calling a parse data retrieve - swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a function in my xcode project in which I'd like to use some data that are on bitnami parse server.

In that function I'm creating a string array which I'd like to load up with my cloumn loc_names in classname Plocations.

My problem is when I calling this function above in my viewDidLoad() I get an empty array. How is that possible?

I was thinking about some kind of thread handling but I'm not sure.

```
func getParseLox() -> [String]{
    var locName = ""
    var locNames = [String]()

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Plocations")

    query.selectKeys(["loc_names"])
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for item in objects {
                var anyu = item.object(forKey: "loc_names") as! String

                print("anyu type:", type(of: anyu) )
                print("anyu: ", anyu)

                locNames.append(anyu)

                print("locnames: ", locNames)
                print("item: ", item.object(forKey: "locName") as! String)
            }

            locName = objects[0].object(forKey: "locName") as! String
            print("these are the selectedKeys ", locName)
        }
    }

    print("locNames array: ", locNames)

    return locNames
}
```

Comment: Does it print into the log

 (print("anyu type:", type(of: anyu) )
                print("anyu: ", anyu))

Comment: yes, it does...

Comment: Does locnames "grow"?

Comment: yes, it does...

Comment: It’s because first you append locnames, then you trash it all and changes locNames into item.object(forkey:...) ...

Comment: this is how it looks like now: https://pastebin.com/VGCPTw0F

Comment: Does it work?       .

Comment: no, all 3 (row 21, 23, 26) are equal to [] and then I see in the log that it iterates through the objects and the list grows